# MapHttpRoute not hitting controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am unable to hit this controller I have three parameters that I am sending from postman but it will not hit the controller at all. Do I have the MapHttpRoute correct?

in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult TemplatesList(string key, string disease = null, string agent = null)
```

in the webAPIConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "FhirTemplates",
                routeTemplate: "fhir/Templates/List/{disease}/{agent}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Fhir", action = "TemplatesList" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route looking some get method like below

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IHttpActionResult TemplatesList(string disease = null, string agent = null)
 {
 }
```

But your controller action has 3 parameters

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult TemplatesList(string key, string disease = null, string agent = null)
```

to fix you need to include `key` parameter in `MapHttpRoute` or you need to remove `key` from your controller